# Does atlas-based imaging segmentation generally involve machine-learning

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Segmentation is an important task in medical imaging analysis.

Many FDA approved medical device use "atlas-based" segmentation tasks. Newer device use "deep-learning based" segmentation approaches. For example https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cdrh_docs/pdf19/K191928.pdf, page 6:

[image]

I wondered if atlas-based segmentation algorithms generally involve machine-learning or not?

I found an [older post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41031/better-machine-learning-methods-for-medical-imaging-segmentation) and an [interesting paper](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/435355.jnrl.pdf), however, both sources do not answer my question.

**Update:**

I moved an [updated version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465717/does-atlas-based-imaging-segmentation-generally-involve-machine-learning?) to stackoverflow to get more attention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP asked already a better version on SO